# Deploying Mobile Automation Testing Tool On Real Device

Tags: java, android, selenium, appium, selendroid

I understand tools like Appium, Selendroid and etc can perform automation testing on the real device via USB cable or even Wifi.

Hence my question here is, is it even possible to deploy Appium/Selendroid on the actual device, like converting it into APK, install it and run it on the actual device?

Any advice or ideal would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No. The Appium Server does not run on Android. You need a Appium host server that runs the tests via USB ADB on the device.